# Serializing Map<String, List<Something>> SimpleXML (Sourceforge)

Tags: java, xml, serialization

I'm using the sourceforge SimpleXML framework to serialize and deserialize some objects into XML. I tried serializing a `Map<String, List<String>>` like this:

```
@ElementMap(attribute = true, inline = true, entry = "block")
private Map<String, List<Something>> map;
```

But it gives me this Exception:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.transform.TransformException: Transform of class java.util.ArrayList not supported
```

So I followed what was said in this thread: [SimpleXml framework - embedded collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027706/simplexml-framework-embedded-collections), and it worked, but it's ugly and the XML are sometimes large enough that that extra lines that the wrapper contributes sum up to be considerable, and I don't like that, especially in a mobile environment.

There's also the issue of reusability, because if I want to reuse the `Map` for another object, I have to write another class that only contains a `List`, and it start to fill my project with classes like this, only to make the serializer happy.

It's there any better solution to this problem?